# Command can't work when I read it from file. ex: echo

Tags: bash

I have two file. one is date_command.txt, the other is job_v3.sh
The content of date_command.txt is "time,command".ex:"1211,service nginx restart"
The code which job_v3.sh is to read file from date_command.txt, and then compare the time with system time.
 
If time is equal, then run the command.
The source code of job_v3.sh is:

```
dateCommand=`cat /root/bash_practice/date_command.txt`
echo $dateCommand

#IFS=',' read -a myarray <<< "$mystring"
IFS=',' read -a dateCommand <<< "$dateCommand"

#echo "Date: ${dateCommand[0]}"
#echo "Command: ${dateCommand[1]}"

DATE=`date '+%m%d'`
#echo $DATE

if [ ${dateCommand[0]} = $DATE ];
then
        echo $DATE
        echo 'Date is the same.'
        echo 'Current Time:'.$DATE
        echo 'Target Time:'.${dateCommand[0]}
        echo 'Command:'.${dateCommand[1]}
        ${dateCommand[1]}
else
        echo $DATE
        echo 'Date is different.'
        echo 'Current Time:'.$DATE
        echo 'Target Time:'.${dateCommand[0]}
        echo 'Command:'.${dateCommand[1]}
fi
```

Now it's ok to run. 
But when command is "echo 1234 >> 1234.txt", it can't run.
Hope somebody can solve the problem for me.
I will very appreciate.

Comment: the command `echo 1234 >> 1234.txt` will run if your `$datecommand[0]` machtes your current `$DATE`
do you mean if you add a second command after `service nginx restart` ?

Comment: just one command. for example: "1215,echo 1234 >> /1234.txt". it can't run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because `>>` is interpreted as literal argument it's due to how shells parse a command, a variable expansion can't change redirection.
see [redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections) and [shell expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions)

to reinterpret literal

```
${dateCommand[1]}
```

can be changed to

```
eval ${dateCommand[1]}
```

`eval` is dangerous you must understand how parsing is done, also executing arbitrary command (comming from file) is dangerous.

Minimal example :

```
cmd='echo 123 >> 123.txt'
$cmd
```

writes on standard output

```
123 >> 123.txt
```

and

```
eval $cmd
```

appends 123 to file 123.ttx